# (DevExpress 19.1) How to make text in field a hyperlink? Currently using HyperLinkEdit but can’t seem to make it multiline

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I am upgrading the objects on my form to DevExpress tools as opposed to the standard WinForm tools.

I am working with a field that contains hyperlinks only, I originally tried to use a MemoEdit but found out after googling that it wasn’t possible to use hyperlinks in this type of field. I seen the RichEditControl get mentioned in a few places but it seems to open a whole control and I’m just trying to make text in a certain field a hyperlink.

So I’ve ended up at the HyperLinkEdit field and it’s working as hoped apart from the fact that the text isn’t wrapped/multi line, meaning that the text just carries on as a single line so on the larger file paths the characters are hidden after a certain length due to it not wrapping and starting a new line.

Could anyone provide a pointer for this? I checked the properties and nothing has jumped out to me and the fact that there’s no multi line property makes me think there isn’t a way to do this using this type of field.

Edit:

[image]

Comment: Is your end goal to have a single, multi-line text field that contains multiple hyperlinks? Is the field editable? I think the easiest method is going to be to use the RichEditControl. You don't need to display any toolbars/rulers etc... and can just display it in simple view, which mimics a MemoEdit control.

Comment: @Brendon I've seen a few comments online about this, but when I used that control it doesn't look like what I'm after at all. If you look at the image I have attached in my edit it looks like an Excel pop up. I'm just after a text field rather than a window like this.

Comment: @Brendon Update: I've now got it looking how I want with a RichEditControl, however the text within the control is not a hyperlink :( Do you know how I can make this a HyperLink?

Comment: Does the text actually start with "http" or "www"?